# What symbols to use on Google Finance and Yahoo finance OMX30

Tags: data

I want to download historical data using `pandas_datareader` for OMX30, however I cant find any symbol which can be found using pandas_datareader.

For example:

- STO:XACT-BULL
- INDEXNASDAQ:OMXS30

Can only be found on [google finance site](https://www.google.com/finance?cid=4420283).

So my question is what symbol can I download that represents OMX30?